# Child Properties Not Persisting in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am just learning Entity Framework in .Net, coming from a Hibernate background in Java.  I am using "code first", however I am doing my own database setup to begin with.  I have a parent object (Submission) with multiple child event logs (SubmissionEvent).  I create my parent Submission with attributes, then my SubmissionEvent with attributes.  I then add my SubmissionEvent to the Submission, and call SaveChanges.

This results in an SQL exception because it is not persisting SubmissionEvent properties that are NotNull columns in the database.  If I make these columns nullable, I end up with a fully populated Submission row, and a row in the SubmissionEvent table with an Id, a Submission_Id, and NULL for other fields.

Things I've tried:
Renaming attributes.  When I do this, I get an SQL exception saying the column doesn't exist.   When I rename the attribute back to the correct name, I no longer receive an error but the attribute is not saved.

Rebuilding class. This is the really weird one.  If I create a new class, called say "SubmissionLog", and persist it by itself, it works correctly.  When I then map is as a child of Submission, it is still persisted but it's basic attributes are not.  Weirdly, if I then remove the association with Submission and restore it to the way it was, the class will still not persist attributes correctly.

SQL Trace.  The inserts for SubmissionEvent just don't include some attributes.

Is there a secret Entity Framework configuration file that I'm missing something?  Something that stores relationships and does... something?  Am I mis-handling my attachments to the dbContext?  I have searched for similar problems but not found any.

Thanks for your time.   Code Below.

```
public class Submission {

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubmissionEvent> Events { get; set; }

    public Submission()
    {
        Events = new List<SubmissionEvent>();
    }
}

public class SubmissionEvent
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Submission Submission { get; set; }
    public string Action;
    public DateTime DateTime;

    public SubmissionEvent() { }
}

public static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Adding Submission: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

        StyxDbContext db = new StyxDbContext();

        Submission submission = new Submission();
        submission.FilePath = e.FullPath;

        SubmissionEvent subEvent = new SubmissionEvent();
        subEvent.Action = "Created";
        subEvent.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        submission.Events.Add(subEvent);

        db.Submissions.Add(submission);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //Console.Write("subContext = " + db.Entry<Submission>(submission).State + "\n");
        //Console.Write("subEventContext = " + db.Entry<SubmissionEvent>(subEvent).State + "\n");
    }
```

SQL Traces

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Submission]([FilePath])
VALUES (@0)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Submission]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ',@0=N'C:\Watch\Solve - Copy (24).txt'

exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[SubmissionEvent]([Submission_Id])
VALUES (@0)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[SubmissionEvent]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()',N'@0 int',@0=1
```

Context State for both objects at the end of the method is "Unchanged"

Comment: Do you ever attach SubmissionEvents to the DB context?

Comment: Initially no, as I believed it would persist from the parent (as Hibernate would).  When it didn't work, I tried multiple combinations, up to and including:  Create Submission, add to context.   Create SubmissionEvent, add to context.   Add SubmissionEvent to Submission.Events.   Set SubmissionEvent.Submission to parent.  savechanges().  

This and all combinations in between produced the same result.  I assume that if the SubmissionEvent was not being attached to context correctly (even in simplified code posted in question), it would not be persisted at all, rather than have missing columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `SubmissionEvent` class, you are using public fields instead of properties, these will not get persisted. Try changing them into properties. I also believe the parent reference has to be virtual. The convention in EF is to make all the referential properties virtual.

```
public class SubmissionEvent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Submission Submission { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public SubmissionEvent() { }
}
```

Comment: Changing them to properties has solved my problem. Thank you for taking the time to point out such an obvious blunder.